# Is there an event or another way to call a Javascript function when a Django Admin Popup (the green plus icon) completes?

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, dom-events

Let's imagine we have those Django models:

```
class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="Eagles of Death Metal")

class Song(models.Model):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band)
```

When using the admin to manage those models, the `band` field is associated to a `Widget` rendered by Django as a `select` html element.

Django's admin also adds a *green plus icon* next to the `select`, clicking it opens a pop-up window where the user is presented with the `Form` to add a new band. When clicking the *save* button in this pop-up window, the new band name is saved in the DB, and automatically assigned to the `select` value.

---

We rely on some javascript to be run each time a `select` value changes.  It is currently listening to the `change` event of said element, which works fine when the user clicks a value directly in the menu proposed by the `select`.

Sadly, when this `select` is populated through the Admin Popup functionality, it seems the `change` event is not fired for the `select`, as our callback is not executed, even though the element's value is actually changed.

Is there another event we can listen to to get the same behaviour than when the user clicks a value directly from the list ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a Javascript snippet with the hackery we use to trigger a change event when the Django admin's add/change popup window is dismissed.

We use this with Django 1.7, so it works for this version at least.

Monkey-patching the Django admin's JS methods to achieve this isn't a very elegant way to do the job, but it was the least intrusive option we found. If anyone knows of a better way, let us all know.

```
/*
 * Trigger change events when Django admin's popup window is dismissed
 */
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // HACK to override `dismissRelatedLookupPopup()` and
        // `dismissAddAnotherPopup()` in Django's RelatedObjectLookups.js to
        // trigger change event when an ID is selected or added via popup.
        function triggerChangeOnField(win, chosenId) {
            var name = windowname_to_id(win.name);
            var elem = document.getElementById(name);
            $(elem).change();
        }

        window.ORIGINAL_dismissRelatedLookupPopup = window.dismissRelatedLookupPopup
        window.dismissRelatedLookupPopup = function(win, chosenId) {
            ORIGINAL_dismissRelatedLookupPopup(win, chosenId);
            triggerChangeOnField(win, chosenId);
        }

        window.ORIGINAL_dismissAddAnotherPopup = window.dismissAddAnotherPopup
        window.dismissAddAnotherPopup = function(win, chosenId) {
            ORIGINAL_dismissAddAnotherPopup(win, chosenId);
            triggerChangeOnField(win, chosenId);
        }

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is the same reply I posted to the Django Users mailing list, but Stack Overflow is a better place for this code snippet to be used or discussed. Here's that discussion thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/7sIM2-9XirY/d6Yr5_fFBwAJ

Comment: Thank you very much, this allowed to implement the functionality. We are using **Django 1.8**, which required only two small changes: the `dismissAddAnotherPopup` should be renamed to `dismissAddRelatedObjectPopup`, and it should take (and forward) an additional argument (`newRepr`).

Comment: Opened [another question related to the Django admin popup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33941944/1027706), in case you have a clue ?