# Pre-populate some of the fields in a Django Admin Popup form (the form appearing when clicking green plus icon)?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

In our Django application, we rely on the contrib.Admin module for data entry.

Let's assume a **simplified example** like this. (the real use case is totally different, but would complicate the presentation without changing the question):

```
class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default="Eagles of Death Metal")

class Concert(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Band)

class PerformedSong(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Band)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    performances = models.ForeignKey(Concert)
```

On the `Concert` admin page when editing an existing `Concert`instance, we can have a formset to add inline instances of `PerformedSong` (as a select widget, listing existing `PerformedSong` instances).

There is also the ability to add a new `PerformedSong` instance, by clicking the "green plus icon". In this case, we would like the `PerformedSong.artist` field to be pre populated with the `Artist` instance corresponding to the concert artist.

How could we achieve that ? Is it possible to pass some initial data through the popup url ?